# Creating random points in a polygon shapefile

Tags: r, shapefile

I am trying to create random plots in a polygon shapefile and then to plot it with index no as 1,2,3,... along with a legend comprising XY coordinates corresponding to each index no.

```
data(meuse.grid)
gridded(meuse.grid) = ~x+y
image(meuse.grid)
plot(meuse.grid, main="Inventory Region")
plots <- points(spsample(meuse.grid, n=10, type='regular'), col='red', pch=20, cex=2)
```

By index I mean a serial no. from 1 to the nth point. np is the object I created based on the sampling intensity, sorry for not clarifying in the question. In my case np = 10. I want to create 10 random points (regular) in a polygon shapefile and then create a plot showing the polygon boundary with all random points with a serial no. assign to each point. I would also like to display a legend with all these 10 points XY Coordinates

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you need.

```
library(sp)
data(meuse.grid)
gridded(meuse.grid) = ~x+y
plot(meuse.grid, main="Inventory Region")
set.seed(1234)
pts <- spsample(meuse.grid, n=10, type='regular')
# Plot point numbers
xy <- pts@coords
npts <- nrow(xy)
points(pts, col='red', pch=20, cex=2)
text(xy[,1], xy[,2], 1:npts, col="red", pos=4)
# Plot table of x y coordinates
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
vp = viewport(x=.1, y=.75, width=.15, height=.3,just="left", clip="on", angle=0)
pushViewport(vp)
tbl <- tableGrob(cbind(1:npts, xy), theme = ttheme_default(base_size=8, padding=unit(c(2,2), "mm")))
grid.draw(tbl)
upViewport()
```

[image]

Comment: @zx8754 Thank you Marco for the solution, it worked. A small issue though, when I am exporting the map the legend is intersecting the map boundary. I tried to change the position to bottomleft but doesn't making any change. Would you be able to provide some option to adjust the legend location into desirable place.

Comment: @amithaldar What do you mean by "exporting the map" ? Are you saving the plot in a file ? If yes, to avoid overlapping of map and legend, you need to enlarge the dimensions (width and height). Let me know.

Comment: Yes, I am saving the plot in pdf format in the destination folder automatically. I tried with different width and height but still, legend is overlapping with the boundary. Although if I stretch the viewer manually then legend is getting adjusted. It would be great if it gets saved automatically. I am using the code as: dev.copy2pdf(file="Random Plots (D015).pdf", width = 7, height = 5)

Comment: @amithaldar This is what I get using `dev.copy2pdf(file="Random Plots (D015).pdf", width = 9, height = 7)`; https://filebin.net/bpjgc8lhd6grl04r  No overlap. If you find useful my anser above, please upvote and accept it. Thank you.

Comment: @zx8754 Hi Marco, I will figure out how to display legend. Thank you very much for the solution, its been really a great help. Unfortunately, my reputation is below 15 at the moment, therefore, can't upvote for your answer but I will do it the moment I cross the threshold. Thank you again for the solution.

Comment: @amithaldar Hi Amit. You can move and resize the legend at your convenience. The solution based on grid is very flexible and can solve almost all the needs.