# Creating a "Random Shapefile"?

Tags: r

I have the following shapefile in R:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75845500/r-find-out-list-of-boundary-coordinates
library(sf)  
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

# built in shapefile
nc <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE) %>% 
    st_transform(st_crs(4326)) %>% 
    st_cast('POLYGON')

nc <- nc[nc$NAME %in% c("Cleveland", "Gaston", "Rutherford", "Burke"), ]  


nc_boundary_coords <- nc %>%
  st_union() %>%
  st_boundary() %>%
  st_coordinates() %>%
  data.frame()

plot(nc_boundary_coords$X, nc_boundary_coords$Y, type = "l")
```

[image]

**My Question:** I am trying to divide this area into "n" random (non-overlapping) subsections - for example, here `n = 8`:

[image]

In the end, I am trying to create a shapefile corresponding to these subsections (i.e. the geographical coordinates).

I found some posts in which I learned how to generate random points within a shapefile (e.g. [Creating random points in a polygon shapefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57819700/creating-random-points-in-a-polygon-shapefile), [R: Check to see if coordinates fall inside/outside of a shapefile polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75669453/r-check-to-see-if-coordinates-fall-inside-outside-of-a-shapefile-polygon)) - but nothing similar to what I am trying to do.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

**Note:** I understand that this is an abstract problem and there are likely many different ways that this problem can be solved (i.e. using different algorithms) - I am interested in learning about different ways to solve this!